# Italic text formatted in Word reverts to regular when saved as PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I italicised a considerable amount of text in a document then saved it as a PDF (Saving it as PDF through Word) (whilst retaining the original document). I noticed that the text that I intended to italicise isn't italicised in the PDF but remained italicised on the Word Document.

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: You will need to make your Word document available for analysis. Which version of Word are you using?

Comment: @harrymc Using MS Word 2019 on Windows 10. The font used is Helvetica. Unfortunately, I cannot publicly put the document online due to a plagiarism service that may flag my own work as plagiarised.

Comment: Make sure the font you are using has an italic variant.

Comment: In the spirit of the comment by @DavidPostill, ensure that Word embeds the font you use in the PDF. If you're doing SaveAs PDF, in Word *Options > Save > Preserve fidelity when sharing this document*, check "Embed fonts in the file" and click OK.

Comment: @DavidPostill How do I make sure that my font has an italic variant? It's practically impossible to tell whether my sans-serif font is using faux italic or not in Word other than it not being shown in the PDF.

Comment: The PDF does not use the same font as the Word document, unless you set "Embed fonts in the file", so the viewer might use a font that has no italics for your kind of font. This might be why the text displays differently in Word and PDF viewer. Try my advice, and if it helps this both verifies the problem and supplies a solution.

Comment: control panel > fonts and look at font style in details view.

Comment: Also, please specify the exact method you are using to create the pdf. There are at least three common methods and a couple more that are not uncommon.

Comment: @harrymc I tried your solution but to no avail

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I just edited my post, if it helps

Comment: Which language+font are you using?

Comment: You have been asked for a sample with the problem. See my article on the Microsoft site. It applies here, too. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: Extract all fonts info from pdf. There are online helpers for that purpose. Some fonts word makes obliques style. not natural italic. As a workaround you could try print as pdf with some soft like pdf24 or similar foss